# Magento 2 + default url needs to traslate

Tags: magento2, multistore, url-rewrite, localisation, translate

Need to translate some default URLs like `customer/account/login/` & `customer/account/create/` is there any way to translate these URLs with/without using URL rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create a language translation file:**

- Go to the Magento root directory.
- Navigate to the following path:
  **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/i18n/** (if the directory doesn't
  exist, create it).
- Create a new file with the name **en_US.csv** (replace en_US with the
  appropriate language code if you're translating for a different
  language).
- Open the file and add the following entries:

> "customer/account/login/", "Your translated login URL"

> "customer/account/create/", "Your translated create account URL"

```
 Replace Your "translated login URL" and "Your translated create 
 account URL" with the respective translations in your desired language.
```

2. **Deploy the static content:**

   Run the following command to deploy the static content:

> **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

3. **Clear the cache:**

   Run the following command to clear the cache:

> **bin/magento cache:clean**

After following these steps, the default URLs **"customer/account/login/"** and **"customer/account/create/"** should be translated according to the entries in your translation file. Make sure to replace **{Vendor}** and **{Theme}** in the file path with your actual vendor and theme names.

Comment: this way is not able to translate URL.

Answer (score 0):

This might partialy answer to your question :

If you have a limited list of URL to translate, you can use the Magento URL Rewrite feature to do this :

Go to "Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites", and click on the "Add URL Rewrite" button.

Then enter the following data :

- **Create URL Rewrite** : Custom
- **Request Path** : enter you translated URL (`client/compte/connexion`)
- ** Target Path** : enter the default URL (`customer/account/login`)
- **Redirect Type** : No

The down side of this method : You will have to edit the templates/methods where those URLs are used in order to use the translated version of the URL instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge URL can not translate without re-write, because url contains the frontname folder name controller file name.